# When asking for the bill - かんじょう or かいけい

Tags: translation, words

Google translate tells me one thing and another dictionary the other.

Is the casual way "Cheku o negaishimasu"

How about the other two words for bill. Are either of those used when asking for a bill?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1743/9831

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a restaurant, 勘定【かんじょう】 and 会計【かいけい】 are almost the same, and you can use whichever you like. Both are often preceded by the "beautifier" prefix お. You can safely say both お勘定【かんじょう】（を）お願【ねが】いします or お会計【かいけい】（を）お願【ねが】いします. Some people on the net seem to say that 勘定 should be used by a customer and 会計 by a clerk, but personally I don't make such a distinction.

チェック (chekku, "check") is not commonly used at a restaurant in Japanese, although you are likely to be understood by those who are used to foreign customers.

勘定 originally means "counting" or "calculation" in general, and it's still sometimes used in this sense when payments are not involved. 会計 is originally a rather technical term for (financial) "accounting". ～を勘定にいれる is a common idiomatic phrase that means "take ～ into account", while we never say ～を会計にいれる.

Comment: Is there regional variation in 会計 vs 勘定? I can't recall (though I wouldn't necessarily hear it often) hearing お勘定お願いします here Hokkaido.

Answer (score 2):

If i made mistakes, Please teaching me.
**Difference between [勘定]{かんじょう} and [会計]{かいけい}**
If you are a customer, Use 勘定. If you are a clerk. Use 会計.

---

So you should use 勘定 in that case. but if you use 会計 in that case. We don't mind. Japanese usually uses 会計.

See also:[Reddit - Learn Japanese](https://www.reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese/comments/2d5c3w/difference_between_%E4%BC%9A%E8%A8%88_and_%E5%8B%98%E5%AE%9A/)