# 会計 kaikei, 勘定 kanjou, チェック chekku and レシート reshiito

Tags: word-choice

I'm sure they all could be used in restaurant bill case. I checked this: [When asking for the bill - かんじょう or かいけい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40326/5010)

But could we also use them interchangeably for these situations?

A. Taxi receipt
B. Shopping receipt
C. Hotel receipt

Or is there any word which we cannot use for one of the situations above? Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When asking for the bill - かんじょう or かいけい](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40326/when-asking-for-the-bill-%e3%81%8b%e3%82%93%e3%81%98%e3%82%87%e3%81%86-or-%e3%81%8b%e3%81%84%e3%81%91%e3%81%84)

Comment: Thanks for noticing the answer for the 勘定vs会計. I have edit my question to focus on the taxi/shopping/hotel situations :)

Comment: Okay, retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use both お会計 and お勘定 in all the situations you listed. But I feel お会計 is more common, especially among young people. (If you are a beginner, I recommend that you always add お before 会計/勘定 because it makes you sound much politer and gentler)

チェックをお願いします would probably be understood at large hotels, but most people never use it.

レシート is totally different, and refers to the small pieces of paper you are handed typically at supermarkets and convenience stores. レシートをお願いします means "give me the receipt (after the payment)" rather than "check, please".

Answer (score 0):

Asking for the bill is different from asking for the receipt.  お会計 and お勘定are asking for the bill but may perhaps be better understood as asking to be rung up.

Asking for a receipt is different and would be レシートor more commonly 領収書。